# PFUser to custom model

Tags: swift, parse-platform, casting, pfuser

I have a model I built for my PFUser from Parse:

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class TradeUser : PFUser {

override class func initialize() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}

var userID : String {
    get {return objectForKey("objectId") as! String}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "objectId") }
}

var emailAddress : String {
    get {return objectForKey("email") as! String}
    set { setObject(newValue, forKey: "email") }
}

var firstName : String {
    get {return objectForKey("firstName") as! String}
    set {setObject(newValue, forKey: "firstName")}
}

var lastName : String {
    get {return objectForKey("lastName") as! String}
    set {setObject(newValue, forKey: "lastName")}
}

var primaryQueue : String {
    get {return objectForKey("primaryQueue") as! String}
    set {setObject(newValue, forKey: "primaryQueue")}
}

var image : PFFile {
    get { return self["profileImage"] as! PFFile }
    set { self["profileImage"] = newValue }
}
}
```

But when I query to get a user, and try to cast it as that, I get a "Could not cast value of type 'PFUser' (0x107555928) to 'ShiftSwap.TradeUser' (0x10754e910)."

I thought that TradeUser would be the same value type as PFUser, since it is a PFUser cast? I'm a little confused, and any clarification would be appreciated!

**EDIT**:

```
@IBAction func chatBarButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let postingUser = self.object?.objectForKey("userID") as! String

    let tradeUserQuery = PFUser.query()
    tradeUserQuery?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: postingUser)
    let trader = tradeUserQuery?.getFirstObject() as! TradeUser

    var chatVC = MessagesViewController()

    chatVC.currentUser = TradeUser.currentUser()
    print(TradeUser.currentUser())
    chatVC.otherUser = trader

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatVC, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Probably you are not casting it correctly. Can I see the code where you cast it ?

Comment: Added! I thought this is how I would do it? Am I mistaking?

Comment: If I print out both TradeUser.currentUser() and trader (without casting) they both come back as PFUser, so I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: You are forcing a downcast which is impossible. You cannot downcast an instance of a superclass PFUser to a derived one TradeUser.

Comment: Ah, alright. So do you have any suggestions as to what I could do? I tried it as a pointer, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Read the parse docs about subclassing...

Comment: Instead of subclassing PFUser, add a PFUser object as a property to your class. The apply those getters/setters on that object instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing a downcast which is impossible. You cannot downcast an instance of a base class PFUser to a derived one TradeUser.

Comment: Would it be the same thing for PFObject?

Comment: Yes. You base class is like a "Car" where you derived class is like a "BMW". Every BMW is always a Car but every Car is not a BMW.